# Find/Replace Text from Headers in a Word Document Using VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I adapted this VBA code to replace all tagged text with what is in the Excel sheet.

This works as intended for the main content in the Word document.

It is not searching/replacing text in the headers of the Word document.

How do I find and replace the text in the headers?

```vb
Dim CustRow, CustCol, TemplRow As Long
Dim DocLoc, TagName, TagValue, TemplName, FileName As String
Dim CurDt, LastAppDt As Date
Dim WordDoc, WordApp As Object
Dim WordContent, WordHeaderFooter As Word.Range

With Sheet106
    TemplRow = .Range("B3").Value 'Set Template Row
    TemplName = .Range("J3").Value 'Set Template Name
    DocLoc = .Range("E" & TemplRow).Value 'Word Document Filename
    
    'Open Word Template
    On Error Resume Next 'If Word is already running
    Set WordApp = GetObject("Word.Application")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        'Launch a new instance of Word
        Err.Clear
        'On Error GoTo Error_Handler
        Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        WordApp.Visible = True 'Make the application visible to the user
    End If

    CustRow = 4
    Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(FileName:=DocLoc, ReadOnly:=False) 'Open Template
    For CustCol = 16 To 180 'Move Through all Columns
        TagName = .Cells(3, CustCol).Value 'Tag Name
        TagValue = .Cells(CustRow, CustCol).Value 'Tag Value
        With WordDoc.Content.Find
            .Text = TagName
            .Replacement.Text = TagValue
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll 'Find & Replace all instances
        End With
    Next CustCol
                                                 
    If .Range("J1").Value = "PDF" Then
        FileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & .Range("Q" & CustRow).Value & _
          "_" & .Range("P" & CustRow).Value & ".pdf" 'Create full filename & Path with current workbook location, Last Name & First Name
        WordDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=FileName, ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF
        WordDoc.Close False
    Else: 'If Word
    FileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & .Range("Q" & CustRow).Value _
      & "_" & .Range("P" & CustRow).Value & ".docx"
       WordDoc.SaveAs FileName
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Put `On Error Goto 0` right before `CustRow = 4` and see if you get any errors when it runs.

Comment: I did as you suggest @TimWilliams and it threw no errors.

Comment: Sorry I hadn't read the whole question and missed the part about the Headers - see for example: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/word/5834-word-find-and-replace-in-header-footer.html

Comment: ... or https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/Customization/ReplaceAnywhere.htm

Comment: You are likely also missing any text in text boxes. I agree, look at https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/Customization/ReplaceAnywhere.htm.

Comment: You also need to improve the way you declare variables. In VBA when you declare variables like `Dim CustRow, CustCol, TemplRow As Long` only the `TemplRow` is a `Long`, the others aren't typed so they get the default datatype of Variant.

Answer (score 0):

Tim Williams and I both recommended looking at the [MVP web page](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/Customization/ReplaceAnywhere.htm) by Jonathan West, Peter Hewitt, Doug Robbins and Greg Maxey. Here is a partial quotation.

**This is Word code so you will need tag it to your WordDoc object instead of ActiveDocument.**

> The complete code to find or replace text anywhere is a bit complex.
> Accordingly, let’s take it a step at a time to better illustrate the
> process. In many cases the simpler code is sufficient for getting the
> job done.

### Step 1

> The following code loops through each StoryRange in the active
> document and replaces the specified .Text with .Replacement.Text:

```
Sub FindAndReplaceFirstStoryOfEachType()
  Dim rngStory As Range
  For Each rngStory In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
    With rngStory.Find
      .Text = "find text"
      .Replacement.Text = "I'm found"
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
  Next rngStory
End Sub
```

> (Note for those already familiar with VBA: whereas if you use
> Selection.Find, you have to specify all of the Find and Replace
> parameters, such as .Forward = True, because the settings are
> otherwise taken from the Find and Replace dialog's current settings,
> which are “sticky”, this is not necessary if using [Range].Find –
> where the parameters use their default values if you don't specify
> their values in your code).
>
> The simple macro above has shortcomings. It only acts on the "first"
> StoryRange of each of the eleven StoryTypes (i.e., the first header,
> the first textbox, and so on). While a document only has one
> wdMainTextStory StoryRange, it can have multiple StoryRanges in some
> of the other StoryTypes. If, for example, the document contains
> sections with un-linked headers and footers, or if it contains
> multiple textboxes, there will be multiple StoryRanges for those
> StoryTypes and the code will not act upon the second and subsequent
> StoryRanges. To even further complicate matters, if your document
> contains unlinked headers or footers and one of the headers or footers
> are empty then VBA can have trouble "jumping" that empty header or
> footer and process subsequent headers and footers.

### Step 2

> To make sure that the code acts on every StoryRange in each each
> StoryType, you need to:
>
> ```
> Make use of the NextStoryRange method
> Employ a bit of VBA "trickery" as provided by Peter Hewett to bridge any empty unlinked headers and footers.
> ```

```
Public Sub FindReplaceAlmostAnywhere()
  Dim rngStory As Word.Range
  Dim lngJunk As Long
  'Fix the skipped blank Header/Footer problem as provided by Peter Hewett
  lngJunk = ActiveDocument.Sections( 1 ).Headers( 1 ).Range.StoryType
  'Iterate through all story types in the current document
  For Each rngStory In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
    'Iterate through all linked stories
    Do
      With rngStory.Find
        .Text = "find text"
        .Replacement.Text = "I'm found"
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
      End With
      'Get next linked story (if any)
      Set rngStory = rngStory.NextStoryRange
    Loop Until rngStory Is Nothing
  Next
End Sub
```

> There is one remaining problem. Just like with the Find and Replace
> utility, the code above can miss any text that is contained in one
> StoryType/StoryRange nested in a different StoryType/StoryRange. While
> this problem does not occur with a nested StoryType/StoryRange in the
> wdMainTextStory StoryRange, it does occur in header and footer type
> StoryRanges. An example is textbox that is located in a header or
> footer.

### Step 3

> Fortunately Jonathan West provided a work around for the problem of
> such nested StoryRanges. The work around makes use of the fact that
> Textboxes and other Drawing Shapes are contained in a document’s
> ShapeRange collection. We can therefore check the ShapeRange in each
> of the six header and footer StoryRanges for the presence of Shapes.
> If a Shape is found, we then check each Shape for the presence of the
> text, and finally, if the Shape contains text we set our search range
> to that Shape's .TextFrame.TextRange.
>
> This final macro contains all of the code to find and replace text
> “anywhere” in a document. A few enhancements have been added to make
> it easier to apply the desired find and replace text strings.
>
> Note:  It is important to convert the code text to plain text before
> you paste: if you paste directly from a web browser, spaces are
> encoded as non-breaking spaces, which are not "spaces" to VBA and will
> cause compile- or run-time errors.  Also: Be careful of the long lines
> in this code.  When you paste this code into the VBA Editor, there
> should be NO red visible anywhere in what you pasted.  If there is,
> try carefully joining the top red line with the one below it (without
> deleting any visible characters.

```
Public Sub FindReplaceAnywhere()
  Dim rngStory As Word.Range
  Dim pFindTxt As String
  Dim pReplaceTxt As String
  Dim lngJunk As Long
  Dim oShp As Shape
  pFindTxt = InputBox("Enter the text that you want to find." _
    , "FIND" )
  If pFindTxt = "" Then
    MsgBox "Cancelled by User"
    Exit Sub
  End If
  TryAgain:
  pReplaceTxt = InputBox( "Enter the replacement." , "REPLACE" )
  If pReplaceTxt = "" Then
    If MsgBox( "Do you just want to delete the found text?", _
     vbYesNoCancel) = vbNo Then
      GoTo TryAgain
    ElseIf vbCancel Then
      MsgBox "Cancelled by User."
      Exit Sub
    End If
  End If
  'Fix the skipped blank Header/Footer problem
  lngJunk = ActiveDocument.Sections( 1 ).Headers( 1 ).Range.StoryType
  'Iterate through all story types in the current document
  For Each rngStory In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
    'Iterate through all linked stories
    Do
      SearchAndReplaceInStory rngStory, pFindTxt, pReplaceTxt
      On Error Resume Next
      Select Case rngStory.StoryType
      Case 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 , 10 , 11
        If rngStory.ShapeRange.Count > 0 Then
          For Each oShp In rngStory.ShapeRange
            If oShp.TextFrame.HasText Then
              SearchAndReplaceInStory oShp.TextFrame.TextRange, _
                  pFindTxt, pReplaceTxt
            End If
          Next
        End If
      Case Else
        'Do Nothing
      End Select
      On Error GoTo 0
      'Get next linked story (if any)
      Set rngStory = rngStory.NextStoryRange
    Loop Until rngStory Is Nothing
  Next
End Sub


Public Sub SearchAndReplaceInStory(ByVal rngStory As Word.Range, _
    ByVal strSearch As String , ByVal strReplace As String )
  With rngStory.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = strSearch
    .Replacement.Text = strReplace
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
End Sub
```